# How to style the first paragraph of a nested block html?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I want to style the first letter of the `<p>` element which is parent of a `<section>` element which has a `<p>` element. I will provide an idea of what I was able to come up with.

**HTML:**

This HTML is not a rigid structure. It may change, by which I mean there are various possibilities for where the first paragraph can occur. My client may have a first section with a paragraph or he may have a paragraph in the second section. That's why I'm trying to use `:has()`

**eg: 1**

```html
<body>
  <section>
    <img src="" alt="" />
  </section>

  <section>
    <p>//something 1</p>
    <img src="" alt="" />
    <p>//something 2</p>
    <p>//something 3</p>
  </section>

  <section>
    <img src="" alt="" />
  </section>

  <section>
    <p>//something 4</p>
    <p>//something 5</p>
  </section>
</body>
```

or

**eg: 2**

```html
<body>
  <section>
    <p>//something 1</p>
    <img src="" alt="" />
    <p>//something 2</p>
    <p>//something 3</p>
  </section>

  <section>
    <img src="" alt="" />
  </section>

  <section>
    <p>//something 4</p>
    <p>//something 5</p>
  </section>
</body>
```

**CSS:**
I have tried these three ways, to me the `1st:` solution should be working but it's not.

**1st:**

```css
section:has(p):first-of-type p:first-of-type::first-letter{
  background: red;
}
```

**2nd:**

```css
section:has(p):first-child p::first-letter{
 background:red;
}
```

**3rd:**

```css
p:first-child::first-letter{
 background:red;
}
```

Here in my examples I only want to target `<p>//something 1</p>` but I keep selecting both `<p>//something 1</p>` and `<p>//something 4</p>`. I think it's happening because everything is in different HTML depth but idk what to do anymore. So help me CSS gods.

Here is a codepen link I have created to demonstrate and play around: **[codepen link](https://codepen.io/woomiz/pen/VwqjjXo)**

**EDIT:** I'm trying not to use class or ID since I will have to create custom widgets to enable a seamless editing experience for my client otherwise he will have to add class manually within wordpress elementor. That said I would like to know if are there any **performance hits** if we make a complex selection like this one so that I can decide whether I have to create a custom widget or not.

Comment: Thank you for making things clearer. So, to paraphrase, you want to find the first p element and this may be in any section (but will be in a section) and it will always be the direct child of a section?

Comment: yes, but the paragraph is not a direct child in the real case. Here I gave it as a direct child as an example.

Comment: OK, so to re-paraphrase, you want to find the very first p element, which will always be within a section element but may be far down in the nesting thereafter?

Comment: yes now it is perfect

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps in your case it is necessary to search for all `section:has(p:first-of-type) ~ section p:first-letter` and reset `:first-letter` `background-color` in `<p>`:

```css
section p:first-of-type:first-letter {
  background-color: red;
}
section:has(p:first-of-type) ~ section p:first-letter {
  background-color: unset;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <p>//something 1</p>
  <img src="" alt="" />
  <p>//something 2</p>
  <p>//something 3</p>
</section>

<section>
   <img src="" alt="" />
</section>

<section>
  <p>//something 4</p>
  <p>//something 5</p>
</section>
```

Comment: This does seem to work but can you also check the edit, I have updated the question.

Comment: This works in codepen but the use of p:first-of-type inside :has() gave me an error while I tested it in production, showing "expected RPAREN at line ... ". I guess CSS parsing issue with the library?

Comment: Which library are you talking about?

Comment: I'm not sure of it myself, but for each elementor widget there is syntax highlighting for CSS inside the `custom CSS` section of advanced tabs of wordpress elementor.

Comment: You can ask elementor developers about it. More likely than not, this is simply because of the use of `:has()`, because it is Selectors Level 4 Specification.

Answer (score 1):

So, you're selecting the first letter of a p element that:

- is contained in a section element
- is not preceded by a sibling p element
- is not preceded by a sibling element that contains a p element
- doesn't have an ancestor that's preceded by a sibling p element
- doesn't have an ancestor that's preceded by a sibling element that contains a p element

I make that `section p:not(p ~ p):not(:has(p) ~ p):not(p ~ * p):not(:has(p) ~ * p)::first-letter`

```css
section p:not(p ~ p):not(:has(p) ~ p):not(p ~ * p):not(:has(p) ~ * p)::first-letter {
  font-size: 3em;
  color:red;
}
```

```html
  <section>
    <img src="" alt="" />
  </section>

  <section>
    <img src="" alt="" />
    <div>
      <p>//something 1</p>
    </div>  
    <img src="" alt="" />
    <p>//something 2</p>
    <p>//something 3</p>
    <div>
      <p>//something 6</p>
    </div>  
  </section>

  <section>
    <img src="" alt="" />
  </section>

  <section>
    <p>//something 4</p>
    <p>//something 5</p>
  </section>
```

Comment: Does this perform well? This looks like a super complicated selection, I was wondering if this has any performance hits when compared to styling the same exact first letter of the first paragraph after giving the section a class or an ID.

Comment: @vishnups - I don't know the performance of this, you'd have to see if it worked OK in your context. There's a lot to be said for finding the paragraph in programming code either client side or server side, and using that instead, yes. But you asked for a CSS solution.

Comment: Your Code does work but I was thinking about performance since both of the solutions provided seem to work and now I'm thinking which is the best solution.

Comment: @imhvost's answer would almost certainly be better performing, but it doesn't work for the sample HTML I've used in my answer. It's unclear to me from your question and comments whether the HTML I've used is a fair representative test of your requirements or an over-complication.

Comment: can you tell me why the 1st CSS solution in my question doesn't work?

Comment: `section:has(p):first-of-type` means match the first section element, if it has a p element descendant. For the e.g.1 example that matches nothing. You need `section:nth-child(1 of :has(p))` to match the first section that has a p element descendant. The question is then whether `p:first-of-type` is sufficient for your needs, given the possible nested structure inside each section element.

Comment: Woah this is so messy, I can't read from LTR. I thought it matched the first type which is a section that has `<p>` as a parent.  Btw all the solutions provided here didn't work for me in the production website due to the use of selectors inside the `()` of selectors like `:not(:has(p) ~ * p)`. The library is giving error for it. So i'm doing it manually for now.

Answer (score 0):

The [`:nth-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type) pseudo class should do it:

```css
section:nth-of-type(2) > p:nth-of-type(1) {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <img src="" alt="" />
</section>

<section>
  <p>//something 1</p>
  <img src="" alt="" />
  <p>//something 2</p>
  <p>//something 3</p>
</section>

<section>
  <img src="" alt="" />
</section>

<section>
  <p>//something 4</p>
  <p>//something 5</p>
</section>
```

Comment: My client may or may not have the first section with an image, So I'm trying to add styling for the first paragraph which may be part of the first section or second. That's why I'm not specifically selecting a section. It's not a rigid structure. It's an example blog post template.